# Powershell to replace a substring with a environment variable passed at runtime

Tags: powershell, replace

I am getting the inputs of a config file and need to replace a particular line with an environment variable which i pass at run time. However the resultant string is exactly the same (no change). I have used the replace keyword.

I have passed the line in replace with single quotes which means it will pass as it is (the string contains certain values in double quotes) and then the expected string in double quotes.

```
$File = Get-Content path of file
if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($env:ai_logging_mode)) **this is the env variable**
{
    $file = $file | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console" />', "<logger name=`"*`" minlevel=`"$env:ai_logging_mode`" writeTo=`"console`" />"};
}
Set-Content -Path path of the file -Value $file;
```

the value of minlevel does not change. I have passed the value as Info. the result should be like

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
```

However the result is still

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console" />
```

Comment: You need to backslash escape the `*` in the first part of the `-replace` since `-replace` uses regex and in regex asterisk is a metacharacter. --> `\*`.

Comment: Thanks that helped !! Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here stems from not escaping regex metacharacters.

The [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6#replacement-operator) operator performs a regex match and replacement of the matched characters. `*` is a quantifier in regex, which will match zero or more characters of the current matched character (the character before the `*`). Regex will match `*` literally if it is backslash escaped, which becomes `\*`. You can also use the `Escape()` method from the Regex class on your string, which will escape the metacharacters automatically.

```
$StringToReplace = '<logger name="\*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console" />'
$StringReplacement = "<logger name=`"*`" minlevel=`"$env:ai_logging_mode`" writeTo=`"console`" />"
$_ -replace $StringToReplace,$StringReplacement
```

To use the Regex class `Escape()` method, you can do the following:

```
$StringToReplace = [regex]::Escape('<logger name="\*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console" />')
$StringReplacement = "<logger name=`"*`" minlevel=`"$env:ai_logging_mode`" writeTo=`"console`" />"
$_ -replace $StringToReplace,$StringReplacement
```